# How to alert when element in a list is clicked?

Tags: javascript

```
    function whatami(img){
      console.log(img.key);
    }

    let animals = ["frog","frog","sheep","sheep","snail","snail","mouse","mouse","bat","bat","walrus",
                        "walrus","giraffe","giraffe","zebra","zebra","dog","dog","octopus","octopus","hippo",
                        "hippo","camel","camel","pig","pig","rhino","rhino","rooster","rooster","panda","panda",
                        "turtle","turtle","raccoon","raccoon","polar bear","polar bear","lion","lion","bison",
                        "bison","orca","orca","snake","snake","shark","shark","toucan","toucan","butterfly",
                        "butterfly","anteater","anteater","seal","seal","armadillo","armadillo","rooster","rooster"]

            var array = shuffle(animals);
            let images = array.map(image => {
              return <img onClick = {whatami(image)} key={image} src={"/animalgameback.jpg"} alt="" className="img-responsive"/>
           });

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {images}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I have this list of images and I need a way to find which one is clicked when I press one of them. How do I do this?

Comment: *'...How do I do this?'* it depends on what you have done so far. If that's React component, would you share the rest of the code?

Comment: did you try onClick event to call some function sending it your current `image` value?

Comment: Before you can "click" .. you need to *display*.  In something.  Like a [grid](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview).  Please show us the code you're using to show something a user can click on.

Comment: I added the rest of what I did...The onclick does not do anything though

Comment: Try `function whatami(img){console.log(img)}` and then `onClick= {() => whatami(image)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click must receive a callback function. Try writing the onClick with a arrow function like this

```
onClick = { () => { whatami(image)} }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write ()=>{whatami(image)} instead of whatami(image). LEt me know if it works.

Comment: just saw Felipe souzas answer